# Old Kable format from 2022 How Do I Update?

Tags: r, kable, kableextra

I have the format set up for KableExtra from early 2023 but tried to run it today and it does not work. It is the Kable_Styling that is having problems

```
'''{r}
home_hitw %>%
  kable() %>%
  kable_styling("striped", "hover", full_width=F,fixed_thead = T) %>%
  scroll_box(width = "1000px", height = "500px")
'''
```

I looked online to see how to update but every time i tried the data never showed up.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  "It does not work" is not helpful.  In what way does it not work?  Do you see error or warning messages?  If so, what are they?  If not, why does the actual output differ from your expectations.  We also need (some of) your data in order to make your question *reproducible*.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a *minimal reproducible* example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: there was an error message but then i updated my kableExtra package and it disappeared. Also the data i am using is protected by the college as it is player data for baseball. How do i upload screenshot? as this would allow me to show you the problem

Comment: Does your run outside of an RMarkdown/Quarto document? Can you edit your question to add the document YAML to make your question reproducible (you can use a built-in data set if you can't share data)?

Comment: As @nrennie suggests, if your real data are confidential, make your question reproducible by using a widely available dataset such as `mtcars` or `iris`.  Uploading a screenshot is straightforward: simply click the relevant button in the question editor.  Edit your question to clarify whether your problem is with the styling of the table, the disappearance of data it is supposed to display, or both.  At the moment, it is very unclear.  In summary, help yourself by helping us to help you.

Comment: Ok i figured it out it was not kableExtra at all just my system not creating the new data set that goes in the kable.

Answer (score 3):

The options for `"striped"` and `"hover"` should be in a vector passed to the `bootstrap_options` argument, rather than passed in as separate arguments to `kabel_styling()`. For example:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

mtcars %>%
  kable() %>%
  kable_styling(
    bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover"),
    full_width = F, fixed_thead = T
  ) %>%
  scroll_box(width = "1000px", height = "500px")
```

Comment: Tried that still no data in my file it has the header.